# SSRS 2016 Report Builder connection to Sharepoint Online List

Tags: reporting-services, sp-online

I was able to connect to my on prem SharePoint 2013 server list, but since we migrated to SharePoint online i no longer get it to connect. I am getting access is denied error.

Account i am using has full access to both SQL and SharePOint site. What am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Your reports will not work with SharePoint Online as a data source because SSRS 2016 Report Builder is not able to use claims based authentication, which is what SharePoint Online uses. [SharePoint List Connection Type SSRS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/sharepoint-list-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

[Explanation of claims based authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh147177(v%3Doffice.14))

Sorry, I'm dealing with the same thing right now and I've spent half the day researching :(

Comment: Have you come across any workaround that works.

Comment: Also does is apply to sharepoint online too?